# Using objectFit with StaticImage from gatsby-plugin-image

Tags: reactjs, sass, gatsby

I am using gatsby-plugin-image's StaticImage component in my web app, and I am having trouble changing objectFit's property from 'cover' to 'contain.'

Here is a sample of my code:

```
import React from 'react'

import { Container, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap'

import { StaticImage } from 'gatsby-plugin-image'

export default function About() {
    return (
        
         <div id="about">
             <Container fluid >
                 <Row className="justify-content-center align-items-center">
                     <Col md={12} >
                        
                        <StaticImage src="../images/coolImage.JPG" objectFit="contain" alt="Profile Picture" />
                        
                    </Col>
                </Row> 
            </Container>
        </div>
            
        
    )
}
```

I have also tried using `style={{ objectFit: 'contain' }}` and `imgStyle={{ objectFit: 'contain' }}` to see if using those props would change the styling. I'm using Sass to style other parts of the website as well, and adding that styling option via Sass and class names isn't working either.

Any ideas as to why the default `object-fit: 'cover'` won't change?

Comment: Can you provide a sandbox?

Answer (score 4):

There's a prop 'objectFit' (along with 'objectPosition') that can be passed to StaticImage directly. I'd try that. My guess is that your passed styles are being overwritten inside StaticImage, but passing the direct props would fix it. https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-plugin-image/

Answer (score 0):

I had to add `style={{height: "100%"}}` as a prop to `StaticImage` in order to make an image cover a full view-height container. The image wrapper does not automatically take the whole space of the container element.